# Java: ArrayList not compiling

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working on a Robot Maze where the robot finds the target without crashing into walls. I know I've missed something or done something incorrectly (most likely a couple of things haha) but I've been racking my brain over it for a couple of hours now and tried several alternatives. I’m pretty sure my error is either where and how I declared the `ArrayList`.

It cannot find the symbol for the `passageDirections` and `nonwallDirections`.

Any help is appreciated :)

PS: I am a beginner programmer, still learning so explain your answer as if you were to explain it to a three year old :)

Comment: You declared statements after `return nonwallExits;`. Those statements will never be reached.

Comment: If your compiler finds a problem in your code, then he will tell you which problem it is and where. Can you give us this information?

Comment: @Tom it cannot find the symbol for passageDirections, nonwallDirections and passageExits

Comment: `passageDirections` there is no variable with that name. `nonwallDirections` your declaring that variable in the `nonwallExits` method. Therefore it is only available there and other methods can't use it. Declare that variable as a [field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html). `passageExits` you're using that as a variable, but there is no variable with that name. You need to call the method with that name: `if (passageExits >= 1)` should be `if (passageExits() >= 1)`.

Comment: @Tom Okay, so I've fixed the `passageExits` error but it still cannot find the symbol for the `passageDirections` and `nonwallDirections`

Comment: I already told you what to do with both variables. And also read the provided link, if you don't know how to do what I suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I for example see a problem here in this method:

```
/* Junction method states if there is more than one passage, it will randomly select one.
    If there is no passage, it will randomly select a nonwall/BeenBefore direction. */
public int junction(IRobot robot) {

    if (passageExits(robot) >= 1) {
        int randomPassage = ((Math.random())*(passageDirections.length()));
        passageDirections.get(randomPassage);
    } else {
        int randomNonwall = ((Math.random())*(nonwallDirections.length()));
        nonwallDirections.get(randomNonwall);
    }
}
```

Here you are using the lists 'passageDirections' and 'nonwallDirections' without declaring them first. I see that you have declared those lists in other functions as **local** variables, which means that they exist as long as the function is executing which they are declared in. So if you want to use them in other functions, you shouldn make them somehow global or pass them around as parameters...

Without fully understanding your code, I would suggest try to do something like this to make the code "compileable":

```
import uk.ac.warwick.dcs.maze.logic.IRobot;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;

public class Explorer2 {

    private ArrayList<Integer> passageDirections = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> nonWallDirections = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private Random random = new Random();

    public void controlRobot (IRobot robot) {
        int exits = nonwallExits(robot);
        int direction;

        if (exits < 2) {
            direction = deadEnd(robot);
        } else if (exits == 2) {
            direction = corridor(robot);
        } else if (exits == 3) {
            direction = junction(robot);
        } else {
            direction = crossroads(robot);
        }

        robot.face(direction);

    }

    /*  Deadend method will make the robot turn around except from the beginning.
        Because the robot can face any direction at the start, it will follow
        the one and only passage it will detect. */
    public int deadEnd (IRobot robot) {

        if (passageExits(robot) == 0)
            return IRobot.BEHIND;
        else
            return -1; //FIXME: return correct direction!!!

    }


    /* Corridor method will make the robot follow the one and only passage. */
    public int corridor (IRobot robot) {

        return -1; //FIXME: return correct direction!!!

    }


    /* Junction method states if there is more than one passage, it will randomly select one.
        If there is no passage, it will randomly select a nonwall/BeenBefore direction. */
    public int junction(IRobot robot) {


        if (passageExits(robot) >= 1) {
            int randomPassage = random.nextInt(passageDirections.size());
            return passageDirections.get(randomPassage);
        } else {
            int randomNonwall = random.nextInt(nonWallDirections.size());
            return nonWallDirections.get(randomNonwall);
        }

    }


    /* Crossroads method states if there is more than one passage, it will randomly select one.
        If there is no passage, it will randomly select a nonwall/BeenBefore direction. */
    public int crossroads (IRobot robot) {

        if (passageExits(robot) >= 1) {

            int randomPassage = random.nextInt(passageDirections.size());
            return passageDirections.get(randomPassage);
        } else {
            int randomNonwall = random.nextInt(nonWallDirections.size());
            return nonWallDirections.get(randomNonwall);
        }
    }


    //Calculates number of exits and stores the direction of the exits in an ArrayList
    private int nonwallExits (IRobot robot) {

        int nonwallExits = 4;

        if(robot.look(IRobot.AHEAD) == IRobot.WALL)
            nonwallExits--;
        if(robot.look(IRobot.LEFT) == IRobot.WALL)
            nonwallExits--;
        if(robot.look(IRobot.RIGHT) == IRobot.WALL)
            nonwallExits--;
        if(robot.look(IRobot.BEHIND) == IRobot.WALL)
            nonwallExits--;

        for(int direction = IRobot.AHEAD; direction < IRobot.LEFT; direction++) {
            if(robot.look(direction) != IRobot.PASSAGE)
                nonWallDirections.add(direction);
        }

        return nonwallExits;
    }


    //Calculates number of passages and stores the direction of the passages in an ArrayList
    private int passageExits (IRobot robot) {

        int passageExits = 0;

        if(robot.look(IRobot.AHEAD) == IRobot.PASSAGE)
            passageExits++;
        if(robot.look(IRobot.LEFT) == IRobot.PASSAGE)
            passageExits++;
        if(robot.look(IRobot.RIGHT) == IRobot.PASSAGE)
            passageExits++;

        for(int direction = IRobot.AHEAD; direction < IRobot.LEFT; direction++) {
            if(robot.look(direction) == IRobot.PASSAGE)
                passageDirections.add(direction);
        }

        return passageExits;
    }
}
```

This way you declare the lists to be instance variables, meaning that they represent the state of an Explorer2 object. Now all the instance methods operating on the Explorer2 objects can access these variables as `this.passageDirections` and `this.nonWallDirections`, where `this` refers to the object you are currently "working on". (and if there are no ambiguities you can skip the `this.` part).

Comment: Thanks but how do i make them global?

Comment: Okay, I have done that but now it says `error: incompatible types: ArrayList<Integer> cannot be converted to int
return passageDirections;` How do I return the only direction in this array list? Also, it now says it cannot find the symbol `method.length()`

Comment: Ah, ArrayList objects have size() methods instead of length(). And we have to change the signature of the corridor() method... I have edited the code above

Comment: you sir are a godsend :) However, it sill doesn't compile :( Could i possibly email you with a picture of the compiling message and perhaps send my code?

Comment: I compiled your code and it increased the errors from 6 to 9 :/ the corridor method has to be an int because otherwise, in the control method when it calls the appropriate direction, it won't work

Comment: That fixed most of it! Although I don't quite understand why it would return -1? Also, the multiplication sign, *, comes up with an error message (possible lossy conversion from double to int)

Comment: Now you made me to actually compile the code :-) I've updated the code above. I hope you at least accept my answer for the effort ;)

Comment: haha of course I accept it! It compiles! do you mind explaining what you did with the random thingy as simply as possible? haha

Comment: haha i have :) mind explaining it?

Comment: And for the random.nextInt(n): It just returns a random integer value between 0 and (n-1), so that you can use it as index, to randomly choose an element in the list...

Comment: you have been a great help and I am stuck on the same project. I was hoping you could maybe help me out via email?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is in the `nonwallExits` method - you cannot have any code after a `return` statement, as this statement terminates the method. Just move `return nonwallExits;` to be the last line of the method and you should be fine.

Comment: ... and in the `passageExits` method (just an info for OP)

Comment: @Mureinik that only solved part of the problem :( it still cannot find the symbol for the `passageDirections` and `nonwallDirections`.

Comment: @codeav3 if you're going to reference these variables from multiple methods, you should declare them as [member variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html).

Comment: @Mureinik I do that by moving the `ArrayList<Integer> nonwallDirections = new ArrayList<Integer>();` lines to the beginning of the class outside of a method right? However, then it says that "ArrayList<Integer> cannot be converted to int" and that it cannot find `method.length()`

Comment: @codeav3 it's quite hard following code in comments like this - can you please post a new question, with the exact snippet that doesn't compile and the exact error message?

Comment: @Mureinik sure thing :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27202349/java-arraylist-cannot-find-symbol