# Java: ArrayList cannot find symbol

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working on a Robot Maze where the robot finds the target without crashing into walls. I know I've missed something or done something incorrectly (most likely a couple of things haha) but I've been racking my brain over it for a couple of hours now and tried several alternatives. I’m pretty sure my error is either where and how I declared the `ArrayList`.

Any help is appreciated :)

I would post a picture of the compiling error messages but I do not have 10 reputation points. Essentially, there are 10 error messages saying it cannot find the symbol for the `passageDirections` and `nonwallDirections`.

PS: I am a beginner programmer, still learning so explain your answer as if you were to explain it to a three year old :)

```
i
```

Comment: Think about the scope of your ArrayList objects.

Comment: @Tom yes it is tom, somebody asked me to post it again if you look at the comments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `passageDirections` variable is local to your `passageExits` method. You can't access it from other methods.

If you want to access it from all methods of your class, make it an instance variable.

The same applies to `nonwallDirections` which is local to `nonwallExits` method.

```
public class Explorer2 {
    ...
    private ArrayList<Integer> nonwallDirections = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> passageDirections = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ...
}
```

Comment: How do I make it an instance variable?

Comment: that worked! But now I have another question. At the dead end and corridor, there will be only one passage in the passageDirections arraylist. How do i return this one and only direction?

Answer (score 0):

You are tyring to access passageDirections and passageExists as a variable but they are methods.  You have to create an private field variable such as

```
private int passageDirections;
```

and update the field in the passageDirections method in order to access them in the way you are trying to.